# How to send cookies to browser on login using ASP.NET Core Identity?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-3.1, asp.net-core-identity

I am building authentication on my asp.net core application using the identity. I followed 2 different tutorials but in both cases, my app doesn't send cookies to the browser. I reckon I am missing something important but I don't know what. Could you point me in the right direction? Here is the relevant code:

```
public class Startup
{
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContextPool<IdentityDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<IdentityDbContext>();

        services.AddControllersWithViews();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> _signInManager;
    private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;

    public HomeController(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager, SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager)
    {
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> SignUp()
    {
        await _userManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityUser("my_name"), "Secret123:");

        return Ok("Signed up");
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> SignIn()
    {
        var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync("my_name", "Secret123:", true, false);

        if(!result.Succeeded)
            return Ok("Sign in failed");

        return Ok("Signed in");
    }
}
```

**Edit:** I created a fresh project and pasted these 2 classes, installed the same NuGet packages there, and the cookies worked. I have a problem somewhere else in the old project. I still have no clue where. I would appreciate if you comment where you think it might be.

Comment: Hi, how are you sure you are not sending cookies to the browser?

Comment: After I make signin or signup calls, I press F12 on Chrome Then go to Application->Cookies tab. There are 2 AntiForgery tokens there but no identity token. @Josh